# U is a $3 \times 3$ matrix such that $U^2 = 0$. Is the matrix $I-U = A$ invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$ be a $3 \times 3$ matrix such that $U^2 = 0$.
This means that $\det(U)^2 = \det(U^2) = \det(0) = 0$, which implies that $U$ is not invertible. Then we have $A = I - U$. Then $AU = (I-U)U = U-U^2 = U$. But I'm not sure how to go from here to determine if $A$ is invertible or not. Could anyone help me? Thanks!!

Comment: D is det I suppose?

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace Yep!

Comment: The inverse of $A=I-U$ is just $I+U$ if $U^2=0$.

Comment: Use the identity $(a+b)(a-b) = a^2-b^2$ in the commutative case you can easily generalize your result for $U^n = 0$ (try geometric sum)

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang  Thank you for the help! I think I've got it.

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace Also thanks for your hint and help!

Comment: You can remember that the inverse of a matrix is always a polynomial in this same matrix

Comment: "Another way you might think to address this problem is to focus on eigenvalues: $I - U$ having determinant $0$ is equivalent to $U$ having an eigenvalue of $1$. But if $Uv = v$, then $U^2v = v$ as well, so $U^2$ also has eigenvalue $1$. So it's not $0$.

Comment: For any polynomial $p$ the eigenvalues of $p(U)$ are of the form $p(\lambda),$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $U.$ Hence if $p(U)=0$ and $p(1)\neq 0,$ then $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $U,$ hence $I-U$ is invertible.